# RichText containing TextField: vertical alignment

Tags: flutter, textfield, vertical-alignment, richtext

I would like to use a RichText widget containing TextSpans as well as inline TextFields (inside WidgetSpans). The TextField text should be aligned to the same vertical baseline as the TextSpans.

How is it possible to achieve this vertical alignment?

I use the following code:

```
RichText(
        text: TextSpan(style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black), children: [
      TextSpan(text: "Text1 "),
      WidgetSpan(
          child: SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "input"),
              ))),
      TextSpan(text: " Text2")
    ]));
```

This leads to the following appearance:

[image: misaligned TextField]

This is how it *should* look:

[image: aligned TextField]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide `PlaceholderAlignment` on  `WidgetSpan`.

```dart
WidgetSpan(
  alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.baseline,
```

The TextFiled height is greater than the text height, you can wrap with a SizedBox. Also I would suggest to play with `Baseline` for this.

```dart
Baseline(
  baseline: 50,
  baselineType: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
  child: RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      children: [
        TextSpan(text: "Text1 "),
        WidgetSpan(
          alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.baseline,
          baseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 50,
            height: 30,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "input"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TextSpan(text: " Text2")
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```